# How to connect with web, which is running on another server

Tags: python, flask, server, vpn

I've connected my PC with other server using AnyVPN and PuTTy. Then I've made simple flask python app (code below):

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def homepage():
    return "Hi there, how ya doin?"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(')
```

When I've tried running that  - it was working. Terminal displayed '* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/' but when i opened the browser and typed that link - my browser didn't display anything. What's more, i haven't root permissions on this server and i've seen that Forwarding function is disabled.

Do you have any idea how can I resolve that?

Comment: Run it on 0.0.0.0

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is the loopback address. It cannot be reached from other computers.

Comment: When I've tried type into the browser 0.0.0.0:5000 or 0.0.0.0 results was the same.

Comment: No change your app.run() to app.run('0.0.0.0')

Comment: Additionaly, also i've put app.run(host='0.0.0.0') into .py file but it also doesn't help

Comment: You need to type the address of the server in your browser.

Comment: I've found ip address after typing ifconfig in putty terminal, but when i put in in the browser (after running server) the result is the same.

Comment: But connecting last a little bit longer - "the conncection has timed out" info was displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, `127.0.0.1` is the loopback address - which is used the refer the same machine (local machine) where this address is looked on.

Since, you have hosted the application in a different server, you can access the application with the IP of that machine which you used to login in PuTTy.

Type `http://<ip_of_remote_machine>:5000` in your browser to connect to your application.

Comment: I've done it with app.run() and app.run('0.0.0.0') and then i've typed 10.133.223.150 (inet adress) into browser and always result is the same.

Comment: After that, webbrowser display that: "the connetction has timed out".

Comment: 10.x.x.x cannot be the public IP address of your server. It is reserved for private usage..

Comment: It's my university server and we have to create simple web app based on flask python. I needn't run it public, but i want to just run my project on that server

Comment: Solved - i haven't noticed that you explain me login issue - i've just used it the same what i've typed in putty and it works!
Thanks!